# has_equal_operator implementation in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I am trying to implement `has_equal_operator` in C++11 and so far came up with following solution. It works for simple cases like `int` or `struct A{}` but fails (returning false positive) for `std::vector<A>`. Why is it failing and how to fix this?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
constexpr auto has_equal_operator(int) -> decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<T>(), bool()) { return true; }
template<typename T>
constexpr bool has_equal_operator(...) { return false; }

struct A {};

void test()
{
    std::cout << "has_equal_operator<int>: " << has_equal_operator<int>(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "has_equal_operator<A>:   " << has_equal_operator< A >(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "has_equal_operator<std::vector<A>>:   " << has_equal_operator< std::vector<A> >(0) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
has_equal_operator<int>: 1
has_equal_operator<A>:   0
has_equal_operator<std::vector<A>>: 1
```

Comment: What do you mean, it's a false positive? Does `==` not work for two vectors for you?

Comment: @immibis `std::vector`'s `operator ==` should only be defined if it is defined for the element type.

Comment: I think this might be something to do with the fact that `bool operator==(const vector<_Tp, _Allocator>& __x, const vector<_Tp, _Allocator>& __y)` is not dependent on the validity of `declval<_Tp>() == declval<_Tp>()`.

Comment: @immibis the has_equal_operator<std::vector<A>> returns true while it really should be false. Since as o11c pointed out A() == A() is not defined

Comment: This is [EWG issue 47](http://wg21.link/EWG47), which was NAD'd, but I don't quite understand the rationale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does it failing?

`std::vector<A>` has a non-member `operator==` function template, which is a match for the `==` in `std::declval<T>() == std::declval<T>()` in your code. So the check succeeds.

The fact that the body of that function template won't compile is irrelevant to SFINAE; all that matters is that the declaration is valid.

> How to fix this?

The only way I can think of is to manually specialize your trait for standard containers.

Comment: Why is it a problem the fact the operator== is a non-member operator?